# express.js and react.js cookie saved to browser but not working?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, cors

I have a backend server using express.js I use react for my front end, so when I log in, the cookie will be saved in the browser but for some reason the session is not persisted and when I try to access some information from some route that requires authentication it will deny the access. I use postman to login and it will persist the session with no problem and can access routes that require authentication, so there must be a problem in the front end that it will not be created here's my codes:

Backend:

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
  credentials: true
}));
```

Front end:

```
const postData = () => {  //this is for login
    const requestBody = {
      username: name,
      password: password,
    };
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      accept: "application/json",
    };
    axios
      .post(`${myUrl}/login`, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

const getData = async () => { //to access some data that requires authentication
    axios
      .get(`${myUrl}/edit`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```

when I log in with my front end I get a success message that I put (successfully logged in) so that means there is no problem with the post request and the CORS there's only one problem which is the front-end, what might be the problem?

PS: what's so interesting is that the cookie is actually saved in the browser but when I try to access some information that requires authentication it denies access!
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code that set cookie?

Comment: I use express-session but as I said it's not the problem the cookie itself is being created and saved to the browser even in postman I can login and persist the session. I don't think there's anything wrong in the server side code. before using react I used ejs for my templating and it worked just fine

Comment: Does your browser have the Cookie and can the backend receive it when you make a request?

Comment: yes my browser has the cookie (see figure above), my back end gets the request but denies access (thinks that I haven't logged in)

Comment: You may need to debug why backend thinks your browser cookie is invalid. Try bypass the auth first and get the cookie from the request after login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to put the credentials to true in the get request as well:

```
const getData = async () => { //to access some data that requires authentication
    axios
      .get(`${myUrl}/edit`, { withCredentials: true })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```